# Do I have to move off the development channel for future releases of kubuntu?

Tags: kubuntu, update-manager

I am currently running Kubuntu 19.04, and considering running the following,

```
update-manager -d
```

To move to the development channel, and thus onto Kubuntu 19.10. If something goes wrong and I encounter some bugs I'm not too worried.

When 19.10 gets released I understand that keeping the OS updated with `apt-get dist-upgrade` or similar, will move me onto the beta, then stable 19.10 when they get released.

When work starts on 20.04 will I then be on the development channel again? Or will I have to run update-manager -d to chose when to go onto the dev channel?

Comment: No you will be on the eoan (19.10) and won't move to 20.04 until you release-upgrade again (it's not rolling; no testing channel like debian); also note 19.10/eoan is not on-topic here until after release, so you won't be able to use this resource for questions. IRC #ubuntu+1 is a resource available for 19.10/next release  (I'm using Lubuntu 19.10 myself)

Comment: and Lubuntu 19.10 is working OK for you? My usage is very basic, chrome, dotnet core, visual studio code, ffmpeg.

Comment: This discussion is off-topic here, as it's a development release.  Issues are extremely rare (if any!), loads more updates (due development) though with freezes (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/EoanErmine/ReleaseSchedule) already passed they are slowing.. I bumped to +1 back pre-17.10 & will move to 20.04 4-5 days after 19.10's release and am yet to need to re-install, but if you need more ping me on irc. If you want to try the daily (as a *live* for example) - http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/milestones/404/builds  (navigate to the flavor; that link used as lower down changes every day)

Comment: ps:  if you give Kubuntu or Lubuntu 19.10 daily a try; `vlc` won't run which is something we know about (nor will it run on any other 19.10 'live' though more significant on k/lubuntu as they include `vlc` by as media player; clicking "affects me too" on bug is appreciated though if you are impacted by it) .. but it will run normally if you install..  Most issues are really minor & few if any notice before they are fixed..  (*cause for `vlc` hasn't been found, kubuntu have a work-around if cause isn't found*)

Comment: I've had problems with VLC in the past, so I use an alternative anyway. KUbuntu 19.10 is working very well. Couple of minor crashes e.g. when playing freecell, and when using the software updater. Hardy an issue though, it's stable where it needs to be.